# Is it possible to use RCS Revision keyword for a depot path?

Tags: perforce

I've managed to use the $Revision$ RCS keyword in Perforce: when I update my file
`//depot/dev_projects/main/src/include/version.h` it will update my define in the file, nicely:

`#define VCS_VERSION "$Revision: #4 $"`

That includes the revision for the version.h file.

What I really need is to embed the **revision for the folder** of my project `//depot/dev_projects/main/src/` to the version.h file. So if someone submits a file for example to //depot/dev_projects/main/doc/readme.txt, I would like to see `#define VCS_REVISION "$Revision: #5 $"` in version.h after I gets the latest revision from depot.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two cases to worry about:  exiting files and new files.  For existing files (and I'm going to assume you are talking about c/cpp files), you can simply 'p4 reopen' the files with the filetype 'text+k' and then submit those files:

```
p4 reopen -t text+k //groovy_project/src/....cpp
```

This would reopen all of the .cpp files in the //groovy_project/src location and make them 'text+k' (the +k means RCS keyword expansion, but I guess you know that since you have keyword expansion working).

For new files, you should use the 'p4 typemap' command.  'p4 typemap' will bring up the typemap in your editor.  This form contains a mapping of files to filetypes for new files added to the depot.  These are the default filetypes that new files will receive (unless a new file added explicitly uses a different filetype when the file is added).  For instance, if you have

```
TypeMap:
       text+k //groovy_project/src/....cpp
```

in your typemap, all new .cpp files in the //groovy_project/src folder will get the text+k filetype, allowing for keyword expansion.

Note, if you explicitly give a new file a different type than what is found in the typemap, the explicitly specified type is used.  Say you had the typemap above.  The command:

```
p4 add -t text ~/projects/groovy_project/src/newfile.cpp
```

this file would get added to the depot as text, and not text+k.

I hope that this information helps.

EDIT:

After reading the edits to your original question, the short answer is no, you cannot add a revision for a folder.  The slightly longer answer is that Perforce doesn't really know about folders/directories. It just knows about files (and therefore the path to the file).  Directories are not really individual objects in the database in a way that would make what you want work.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I could not made myself clear, so I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks again, your edit seems to be the case. Folder is not an entity for p4. Maybe commit hooks could help, but I'm not using p4 any more. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the $File$ keyword:

http://kb.perforce.com/article/54/using-rcs-keywords

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've needed something like $Revision$, but for folders.